# svn commands fail with SSL: bad packet length on Solaris

Tags: ssl, svn, solaris

I have a host with Solaris installed:

```
# uname -a
SunOS <hostname> 5.10 Generic_147147-26 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V250
```

When I'm trying to execute any svn command as non-root user to a remote repository I'm getting SSL error:

```
<username># svn log https://svn.example.com/repository/file 
SSL negotiation failed: SSL error: bad packet length
```

But if I switch to a root user everything seems to work fine:

```
root# svn log https://svn.example.com/repository/file
Authentication realm: <https://svn.example.com:443>
Password for 'root':
```

I've tried to remove `ssl.svn.server/<hash>` file for remote host and this works for root account (I have to accept the certificate again) but I'm getting the same SSL error for non-root user.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Post the output from `which svn` and then `ldd -s /path/to/svn` for both `root` and your normal user account.  You might have differences in environment variables such as `PATH` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: The result of `username# which svn` is `/opt/local/bin/svn`. Subversion is not installed for root so I was using `/opt/local/bin/svn log ...`. I've tried to do ldd for both users and got `ldd: /opt/local/bin/svn: unsupported or unknown file type`

Comment: That probably means `/opt/local/bin/svn` is a script.  Still, it's probably an environment difference.  Do you have any `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables set for either `root` or your user account?  `env | grep LD_` will show them.  Don't just look for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Only user has `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in his environment. root does not have anything with `LD_`. Weird thing is that I have several almost identical Solaris hosts that share the same home directory and environment for each non-root user (automount, etc.) and svn works just fine on them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the regular user "username" had accepted a previous/different certificate from that host?
You may try to remove or rename the .svn directory into your "username" home and see if it solves the issue: if this is the case probably your "username" have stored some wrong setting in its .svn settings files.

Is it possible that root and "usarname" are using a different svn executable due to $PATH order? (You may check it using `which svn` command).

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've checked the certificates manually and they are exactly the same. I've even copied root certificate to username and still got bad packet lenght error.

Comment: Which version of svn are your running on the client side and on the server side?
Have you tried removing the .svn in the home of "username"? I feel like there might be an issue in the conf files.

Comment: Alternatively you may try with a different non-root user to understand if the issue it related to your "username" settings or it's due to machine settings.
I'd use a fresh new user for this test.

Comment: svn is kinda outdated: `svn, version 1.6.3 (r38063)` Unfortunately I can't verify svn version on a server side. But root and non-root users both use the same binary/script to connect to a server so I'm guessing that this problem exists not because of version differencies. I've also tried to remove `.subversion` from non-root user home directory and it didn't help: svn command creates another one and still throws bad packet length error. The problem also persists for other non-root users (and I've got plenty of them on this host).

Comment: @GGorge, wow this seems to be a very hard problem, are the regular users able to access ssl global configuration files in `/etc/ssl`, `/opt/etc/ssl` and `/etc/certs`?
Having some more time I'd try one (or both) of the following:
* Compile and/or install a newer svn version on the users area (svn is not that difficult to compile on Solaris if you have the build tools)
* Run regular users svn under truss to try understanding if the failure is related to some permission issue or library load issue
I know these are time consuming but honestly I have no better ideas.

Comment: The problem is a bit tricky, yes. If you check my replies to Andrew Henle above you'll see that I have several almost identical hosts with the same hardware and software configuration (especially shared home direсtory and environment). And the problem exists only on this particular host. svn itself is also shared so newer svn version is not a solution unfortunately.

Comment: I've tried to make svn more verbose and this is what I've got: https://pastebin.com/qqxRWU7z